# How is the camera preview connected with the final image output?

Tags: android, android-camera

I've always been under the impression that the preview and the final output are not connected in any way; meaning that I can set the preview to be some arbitrary dimension and that the final JPG will be whatever specific resolution I set in to be in the params, but I just ran into a very odd situation where the image data coming back in the byte[] that's in the jpg callback is different, depending on what dimensions I set my preview to.

Can someone enlighten me on what actual relationship the preview has on the final JPG? (or point me to documentation on said relationship).

TIA

[Edit]
As per ravi's answer, this was my assumption as well, however, I see no alternative but to surmise that they are, in fact, directly connected based on the evidence.  I'll post code if necessary (though there's a lot of it) but here's what I'm doing.

I have a preview screen where the user takes a photo of themselves. I then display the picture captured (from the jpg callback bitmap data) in a subsequent draw view and allow them to trace a shape over their photo. I then pass the points of their polygon into a class that cuts that shape out of the original image, and gives back the cut image.

All of this works, BUT depending on how I present the PREVIEW, the polygon cutting class crashes on an array out of bounds index as it tries to access pixels on the final image that simply don't exist.  This effect is produced EXCLUSIVELY by altering the shape of the preview View's dimensions. I'm not altering ANYTHING else in the code, and yet, just by mis-shaping my preview view, I can reproduce this error 100% of the time.

I can't see an explanation other than that the preview and the final are directly connected somehow, since I'm never operating on the preview's data, I only display it in a SurfaceView and then move on to deal exclusively with the data from the JPG callback following the user having taken their photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation between the preview resolution and the final image that is captured.

They are completely independent (at least for the still image capture). The preview resolution and the aspect ratio are not interrelated with the final image resolution and the aspect ratio in anyway.

In the camera application that I have written, the preview is always VGA but the image I capture varies from 5M to VGA (depending on the device capability)

Perhaps if you can explain the situation it would be more helpful.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I think this has something to do with your scaling factor than the preview. You will have to first convert the coordinates from the device origin to the image origin and then apply the correct scaling factor to map it to the original sized image.

Answer (score 1):

We are currently developing a camera application and face very similiar problems. In our case, we want to display a 16:9 preview, while capturing a 4:3 picture. On most devices this works without any problems, but on some (e.g. Galaxy Nexus, LG Optimus 3D), the output camera picture depends on the preview you've chosen. In our case the outcoming pictures on that devices are distorted when the preview ratio is different from the picture ratio.

We tried to fix this, by changing the preview resolution to a better one just before capturing the image. But this does not work on some devices and occure error while starting the preview again after capturing is finished.
We also tried to fix this, by enlarging the SurfaceView to fullscreen-width and "over fullscreen"-height to make a 16:9 preview out of a 4:3 preview. But this does not work, because SurfaceViews can not be higher then screenheight.

So there IS any connection on SOME devices, and we really want to know, how to fix/workaround this.